# Coloring An Octagon

Tags: combinatorics

**Question**

How many ways can we color the sides of the octagon with $8$ colors so that every side gets a different color?

**My Approach**

We can color any side using $8C1$ colors. then $7C1, 6C1, \ldots, 1C1$. So the total number of ways is $8!$.

We can color $8$ sides alternating the colors. I mean each side can be colored with one of the $8$ colors once. So total number of ways is $8 \cdot 8 = 64$.

But both of the answers are incorrect.

**Note:**
As I said while asking my first question, I don't know much combinatorics.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your previous question was more "problematic", so to speak. One needed to see how to apply combinatorics in an unusual situation (Trojan war, horses etc.). This one should be a lot more straightforward. You should be almost there with $8!$ ways. (Forget the "alternating colours"!) The only thing is - have you counted some identical colourings as different? For example, if you rotate or reflect the octagon, do you get a new colouring or the same colouring? The statement of the problem should be more precise about that.

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot brother @StinkingBishop to help me out with this problem..
i didn't count identical colourings as different.

Comment: brother. as every side is getting a different color from those 8 colors .. if i rotate the octagon, there should be a new color.

Comment: And ... what solution is the one you expect to get? $7!=5040$? $7!/2=2520$?

Comment: I tried these answers while i was working with different kind of answers. but that's not working

Comment: I am out of my wits. The problem is, as I said, ambiguous, but if the solution is neither of $8!=40320$, $7!=5040$ or $7!/2=2520$ then I don't know how I should interpret it. Where is this problem coming from?

Comment: @StinkingBishop.... this problem is for a octagon created with planes. it's in the language bengali. But you can translate into the language in what you like. I hope google translate would do it perfectly. 
Here's the question link : https://gonitzoggo.com/archive/problem/8

Comment: Aah, is it an *octahedron* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron )?!! If yes, then you don't divide $8!$ by either $8$ or $16$ but by the *number of symmetries* of the octahedron (i.e. different orientations that the same octahedron can have, resulting in seemingly different, but actually same colourings), which is ... either $24$ (rotational only) or $48$ (all symmetries) - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry . Thus, the answer is most likely $8!/48=840$, and less likely $8!/24=1680$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop bro.... you are a genius... answer is 1680... thankssssssss a loottttt ........
and sorry bro... i was inactive for a while...so i saw it late